# Cannot generate html report using DotCover console runner

Tags: c#, resharper, code-coverage, nunit-3.0, dotcover

I am running dotcover command line tool on my unit test project. As specified by https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html#, I run the following command

```
C:\files\dotcover cover
    /TargetExecutable="C:\files\MockTestSample\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe"
    /TargetArguments="C:\files\mocktestsample\Tests\bin\Debug\tests.dll"
    /Output="SampleCoverageReport.json"
    /ReportType="JSON"
```

it beautifully generates the report data in a json format. But when I try to generate an html report:

```
C:\files\dotcover\dotcover cover
    /TargetExecutable="C:\files\MockTestSample\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe"
    /TargetArguments="C:\files\mocktestsample\Tests\bin\Debug\tests.dll"
    /Output="SampleCoverageReport.html"
    /ReportType="HTML"
```

I simply want to see the code coverage report as html. However, when I go to my SampleCoverageReport.html file, I did see the coverage, but I am not able to see the sources. When I clicked on a project it says "no source available".
Am I missing something? I just followed what is written exactly in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating an HTML report dotCover tries to find source code files using paths saved by the compiler in pdb files. If these paths are not valid anymore (e.g. the source files have been moved/deleted after the compilation, or if your application has been built on some other machine), than dotCover can't include source code to the HTML report.

Starting with version 2020.1 there will be a new command line parameter 'SourcesSearchPaths' where you will be able to specify actual path(s) to the source code.

Also please note that source code is available only for method nodes of the coverage tree.

Comment: I am using nunit. Is it possible that shadow coppiing causes the .pdb files to be moved? If so how to get around this?

Comment: No, pdb files are ok. dotCover did found pdb files successfully (otherwise you wouldn't see any coverage data at all). It can't find your *.cs files.

Comment: @morbidCode Could you please open an issue in dotCover's bug tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DCVR) and provide me your coverage snapshot (in order to get it, start 'cover' command without 'ReportType' parameter)?

Comment: @EkaterinaSolovova I'm having a similar problem where sometimes, the "src" section of the report wouldn't get generated. I still see the index page with the report summary, but I wouldn't be able to browse to individual .cs files to visually see the code coverage. What would contribute to this randomness? I did verify that all the pdb files are in my target directory.